# code that works in sql database doesn't work in php website

Tags: php, html, sql

```
$sql = "select sum(case when 'Social Media Opinion'='I like social media.' and 'Social Media Usage'='Every day' then 1 else 0 end) as ye from svar2;";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo "<thead>";
     echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td>Internet Fatigue out of 10</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
echo "<thead>";
if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tbody>";
             echo "<tr>";
                 echo"<td>". $row['ye'].             "</td>";
             echo "</tr>";
        echo "</tbody>";
    }
}
```

This code will find out the number of people who answered "I use social media everyday" and "I like social media."
I am trying to run this code which finds the sum of people who have answered specific answers to both questions. When I run it in PHP my admin, it works fine, but when I run it in my PHP website, it errors with

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_num_rows(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SPU\index.php:140 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\SPU\index.php(140): mysqli_num_rows(false) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\SPU\index.php on line 140

please help

Comment: You have a column called `Social Media Opinion`? Objectnames shouldn't have spaces, if they do you need to quote them: `"encapsulate"` (I believe mySQL uses backticks).

Comment: Are you certain that query "_works in sql database_"? Which tool did you use?

Comment: the parts with spaces work because i quoted them in this ``. it has worked before.

Comment: the tool i used was xamp phpmyadmin